# Overriding yylex() in Bison's C++ API

Tags: bisonc++

I have a handwritten parser in C++ which contains a `next_token()` method and I wanna use it inside `yylex()` (I already did that correctly with Bison's C API but wanna use dynamic types so moved to C++). I [read these parts of documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Scanner-Interface), read examples and tried both existing signatures but still can't do it correctly...

parser.yy:

```
%require "3.2"
%language "c++"
%define api.value.type variant
%define api.token.constructor
%define parse.assert
%code requires
{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
}


%code{
    yy::parser::symbol_type yy::parser::yylex();
    void yy::parser::yyerror(const char *error);
}

%token VAR COL ITYPE
%token IDENTIFIER
%token INTEGER
%token EOL

%type <std::string> type PrimitiveType IDENTIFIER
%type <int> INTEGER    

%%
program:
| program EOL
| program SimpleDeclaration {  }
;

SimpleDeclaration: VariableDeclaration
;

VariableDeclaration: VAR IDENTIFIER COL type {std::cout<<"defined variable " << $2 << " with type " << $4 << std::endl; }

type: IDENTIFIER
| PrimitiveType
;

PrimitiveType: ITYPE { $$ = "int"; }
;

%%
void yy::parser::yyerror(const std::string& m)
{
    std::cout << "syntax error" << std::endl;
}
// also 'yy::parser::symbol_type yy::parser::yylex(semantic_type* yylval)' does the same
int yy::parser::yylex(semantic_type* yylval)
{
    return 0; // just returning a zero for now
}


int main()
{
    yy::parser p;
    return 0;
}
```

Errors :

```
bison -d parser.ypp
g++ -std=c++17 -o foobar parser.tab.cpp
parser.ypp:14:29: error: no declaration matches ‘yy::parser::symbol_type yy::parser::yylex()’
   14 |     yy::parser::symbol_type yy::parser::yylex();
      |                             ^~
parser.ypp:14:29: note: no functions named ‘yy::parser::symbol_type yy::parser::yylex()’
In file included from parser.tab.cpp:41:
parser.tab.hpp:193:9: note: ‘class yy::parser’ defined here
  193 |   class parser
      |         ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:15:10: error: no declaration matches ‘void yy::parser::yyerror(const char*)’
   15 |     void yy::parser::yyerror(const char *error);
      |          ^~
parser.ypp:15:10: note: no functions named ‘void yy::parser::yyerror(const char*)’
In file included from parser.tab.cpp:41:
parser.tab.hpp:193:9: note: ‘class yy::parser’ defined here
  193 |   class parser
      |         ^~~~~~
parser.tab.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int yy::parser::parse()’:
parser.tab.cpp:453:38: error: ‘yylex’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘yylen’?
  453 |             symbol_type yylookahead (yylex ());
      |                                      ^~~~~
      |                                      yylen
parser.ypp: At global scope:
parser.ypp:45:6: error: no declaration matches ‘void yy::parser::yyerror(const string&)’
   45 | void yy::parser::yyerror(const std::string& m)
      |      ^~
parser.ypp:45:6: note: no functions named ‘void yy::parser::yyerror(const string&)’
In file included from parser.tab.cpp:41:
parser.tab.hpp:193:9: note: ‘class yy::parser’ defined here
  193 |   class parser
      |         ^~~~~~
parser.ypp:50:5: error: no declaration matches ‘int yy::parser::yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type*)’
   50 | int yy::parser::yylex(semantic_type* yylval)
      |     ^~
parser.ypp:50:5: note: no functions named ‘int yy::parser::yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type*)’
In file included from parser.tab.cpp:41:
parser.tab.hpp:193:9: note: ‘class yy::parser’ defined here
  193 |   class parser
      |         ^~~~~~
```

I feel weird also that even without overriding, it seems to use `yylex` here (which causes the error to appear even though I don't try to override):

```
parser.tab.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int yy::parser::parse()’:
parser.tab.cpp:453:38: error: ‘yylex’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘yylen’?
  453 |             symbol_type yylookahead (yylex ());
      |                                      ^~~~~
      |                                      yylen
```

What did I do wrong here ?
Thanks in advance